# How to use defaultOnFocusComponent and onFocusChanged of react native camera

Tags: android, react-native

Who knows tap-to-focus with react native camera? If you know, I hope that everyone will help me.

I am doing a app that used to taking a picture. I want to focus a object when I touch the object on the screen. I used property of Camera include:

```
defaultOnFocusComponent={true}

onFocusChanged={this.onFocusChanged}
```

in `this.onFocusChanged`:

```
onFocusChanged(e)
{
    console.log('hello world');
}
```

The problem is it not run when I watch `console.log` by "react-native log-android" but I don't see anything  happen.

I hope for your supportive help.